# Blink effect when switching between Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]Have problems when switching from main form to another form where was set data by background worker. At switching happen blinking.

At debugging my second form looks like this.

```
backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += LoadFixedAssetListFromHorizonForTable;
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += LoadFixedAssetListFromHorizonForTableCompleted;
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
{
    loadingForm.ShowForm("Loading...");
}

mainMenuForm.Hide();
fixedAssetListForm.Show();
```

But if change code. Form dont blink, only have form with clear zones like [1] image for 0.5 seconds.

```
fixedAssetListForm.SuspendLayout();

mainMenuForm.Hide();
fixedAssetListForm.Show();

Thread.Sleep(500);
fixedAssetListForm.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: Blinking? In what sense?

Comment: WinForms isn't WPF

Comment: It looks like form hide and show doing fast but data set into form and InitializeComponent happen much slower that form is showed.

Comment: john, added image maybe it helps.

Comment: Id suggest you record something and put it up on youtube as a hidden listing to show the "blinking" because other than your pic shows incomplete drawing of the form.. its hard to tell with what you've done.. as to what can be wrong with it.

Comment: Added gif image.

Comment: This is common problem in winforms applications. The backgroundworker is not related to this problem. The flickering is happening because form is shown before all components are drawed. I'll try found some example how to (almost globaly) workaround this (standard) behaviour.

Comment: if you show the second form as dialog, then why hide the first form ? Keeping it visible beneath the dialog form might not have the flickering effect and seems like normal behavior to me. I dont know your specs off course

Comment: I am sorry, i show second form as Show, not ShowDialog. But problem also happen same with ShowDialog and Show.

Comment: Like I said, this isn’t WPF.  WinForms is hardly a bastion of flicker-free display.  You can achieve it manually by rendering to a offscreen bitmap then shoot it to the screen but you are dealing with dialogs.

Comment: MickyD, i saw your message about WPF, but project also create in WinForms. Will try to fix this problem. Also thanks for your response.

Comment: I guess your Progress Bar is adding up to the flickering. Try keeping a thread sleep, how does that look like?

Comment: Yes, i tried put Thread.Sleep at different cases, like: form shown, form load, form activate, form show, form hide and in background worker. But delay dont helps.

Comment: Did you try putting the progress bar inside the `fixedAssetListForm` instead on the dashboard window? Also is your `fixedAssetListForm` dependent on background worker completion? If yes, try putting a delay in the background worker completed hander and check. If nothing work then try putting thread sleep just before the line where you show the new window.

Comment: Siva Gopal, don't help.

Comment: SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout with delay helps, but have clear zone. Code in topic.

Comment: Thanks soo much everyone who helped me with your answer response to brainstorm this topic. I fixed this by: 1) removed UI component update in brackground worker 2) second part bug was in Visual Studio when VS not minimized UI rendering dont work correctly, in minimized or in build works fine.

Comment: Can someone tell how close this topic without answer and deleting?

Comment: Post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: How about set `DoubleBuffered = true` ?

Comment: LarsTech, thanks. Now need await two day for accept my answer.)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by: 
1) removed UI component update in brackground worker 
2) second part bug was in Visual Studio when VS not minimized UI rendering dont work correctly, in minimized or in build works fine.